# Array.prototype.reduce(), filtrar resultados

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
const tasksArray = []
const tasks = document.getElementById('tasks');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
const form = document.getElementById('form-tasks');
const formEdit = document.getElementById('form-edit');
const find = document.getElementById('find')
const search = document.getElementById('btn-find')
const formSearch = document.getElementById('form-search')

// Insertar o actualizar tarea
const redraw = (task, index) => {
    // Crear HTML con plantillas de texto
    const template = `<li>
      <p>${task}</p>
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
      </li>`;
    if (index < 0) {
        // Agregar tarea
        tasks.innerHTML += template;
        tasksArray.push(task);
    } else {
        // Actualizar tarea
        const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
        if (items && items[index]) {
            // Solo si realmente existe
            // OuterHTML remplaza todo el elemento
            items[index].outerHTML = template;
            tasksArray[index] = task;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('vacio').innerHTML = '';
};
// Función para obtener índice de elemento
const taskFind = (item) => {
    const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
    // Valor si no se encuentra el elemento
    let index = -1;
    // Recorrer para buscar
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] == item) {
            // Elemento encontrado, actualizar índice y salir del ciclo
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Devolver índice o -1
    return index;
};
//Funcion para buscar
const buscar = (query) => {
    return tasksArray.reduce((acumulator, element, indx) => {
        if (element.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            acumulator.push({ element, indx })
        }
        return acumulator
    }, [])
}

// Función para borrar, recibe evento
const taskDelete = (e) => {
    // e.target es el botón
    // .closest('li') selecciona el contenedor al que pertenece el botón
    index = taskFind(e.target.closest('li'));
    // Agregar confirmación
    if (index >= 0 && confirm('¿Borrar tarea?')) {
        // Eliminar
        e.target.closest('li').remove();
        tasksArray.splice(index, 1);
        if (tasksArray.length == 0) {
            const vacio = document.getElementById('tasks');
            vacio.innerHTML = '<h1>No hay tareas...</h1>';
        }
    }
};
// Función para editar, recibe evento
const taskEdit = (e) => {
    index = taskFind(e.target.closest('li'));
    if (index >= 0) {
        // Abrir modal enviando índice de elemento a editar
        openModal(index);
    }
};

// Abrir modal, recibe índice del elemento
const openModal = (index) => {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    // Asignar índice a dataset de formulario, para saber cuál se está editando
    formEdit.dataset.index = index;
    // Asignar valor a campo de formulario
    document.querySelector('#edit-task').value = tasksArray[index];
}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const task = document.getElementById('task')
    const tasksText = task.value
    task.value = ''
    if (tasksText === '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea!')
    } else {
        // Insertar elemento en arreglo y mostrar
        redraw(tasksText, -1);
    }
});

formEdit.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const edit = document.getElementById('edit-task');
    const value = edit.value;
    if (value == '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea');
    } else {
        // Cerrar modal
        modal.style.display = 'none';
        // Actualizar valor, en dataset está el índice del elemento
        redraw(value, parseInt(formEdit.dataset.index));
    }
});
//FormSearch
formSearch.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = find.value
    if (value == '') {
        redraw()
    } else {
        console.log(buscar(value));
    }
})

// Delegar clics para activar botones
tasks.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const item = e.target;
    // Buscar botón por clase
    if (item.classList.contains('delete')) {
        taskDelete(e);
    } else if (item.classList.contains('edit')) {
        taskEdit(e);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.content-left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.content-right {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li>button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    display: inline;
}


/* Modal */

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-left">
            <form id="form-tasks">
                <label>Add a Task</label>
                <input id="task" type="text" placeholder="Task..." />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <form id="form-search">
                <label>Search Task</label>
                <input id="find" type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
                <input id="btn-find" class="find" type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol id="tasks">
        <div id="vacio">
            <h1>No hay tareas...</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- <li>comer <button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>jugar</li> -->
    </ol>

    <!-- Modal -->

    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form-edit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-task" />
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btn-modal" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

en el texto, donde puse buscar,
he creado una funcion con reduce, para filtrar los elementos de acuerdo a lo que escriba en el buscador, en consola se puede observar que la funcion me regresa el resultado si es que encuentra una coincidencia, y si no la encuentra devuelve un arreglo vacio, no se como pintarlos en pantalla con todas sus funcionalidades,
editar y eliminar, el texto de buscar esta dentro de un formulario y con el evento de submit, puedo capturar lo que se escribe en el texto
la funcion tambien me devuelve el indice del arreglo original,
o si existe una forma mejor de hacerlo estaria genial
gracias por si ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El arreglo y los elementos de lista (li) están relacionados por índice, entonces, en la función `buscar()` solo necesitas devolver un arreglo de índices que coinciden con la búsqueda.

Cuando se hace clic en el botón buscar:

- Obtienes todos los elementos de la lista, los vas a necesitar para cualquiera de los casos disponibles
- Si el valor a buscar es vacío, muestras todos los elementos
- Si hay un valor a buscar:

  - Primero ocultas todos
  - Recorres los índices de los elementos que cumplen la condición y muestras solo esos

**Nota:** Cuando aplicas estilo `display = 'none'` el elemento se oculta y, si es una cadena vacía, el estilo se restablece al valor por defecto que corresponda a la etiqueta o al que hayas especificado en hoja de estilos.

```js
const tasksArray = []
const tasks = document.getElementById('tasks');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
const form = document.getElementById('form-tasks');
const formEdit = document.getElementById('form-edit');
const find = document.getElementById('find')
const search = document.getElementById('btn-find')
const formSearch = document.getElementById('form-search')

// Insertar o actualizar tarea
const redraw = (task, index) => {
    // Crear HTML con plantillas de texto
    const template = `<li>
      <p>${task}</p>
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
      </li>`;
    if (index < 0) {
        // Agregar tarea
        tasks.innerHTML += template;
        tasksArray.push(task);
    } else {
        // Actualizar tarea
        const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
        if (items && items[index]) {
            // Solo si realmente existe
            // OuterHTML remplaza todo el elemento
            items[index].outerHTML = template;
            tasksArray[index] = task;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('vacio').innerHTML = '';
};
// Función para obtener índice de elemento
const taskFind = (item) => {
    const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
    // Valor si no se encuentra el elemento
    let index = -1;
    // Recorrer para buscar
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] == item) {
            // Elemento encontrado, actualizar índice y salir del ciclo
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Devolver índice o -1
    return index;
};
//Funcion para buscar
const buscar = (query) => {
    return tasksArray.reduce((acumulator, element, indx) => {
        if (element.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            // Obtener solo índice
            acumulator.push(indx)
        }
        return acumulator
    }, [])
}

// Función para borrar, recibe evento
const taskDelete = (e) => {
    // e.target es el botón
    // .closest('li') selecciona el contenedor al que pertenece el botón
    index = taskFind(e.target.closest('li'));
    // Agregar confirmación
    if (index >= 0 && confirm('¿Borrar tarea?')) {
        // Eliminar
        e.target.closest('li').remove();
        tasksArray.splice(index, 1);
        if (tasksArray.length == 0) {
            const vacio = document.getElementById('tasks');
            vacio.innerHTML = '<h1>No hay tareas...</h1>';
        }
    }
};
// Función para editar, recibe evento
const taskEdit = (e) => {
    index = taskFind(e.target.closest('li'));
    if (index >= 0) {
        // Abrir modal enviando índice de elemento a editar
        openModal(index);
    }
};

// Abrir modal, recibe índice del elemento
const openModal = (index) => {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    // Asignar índice a dataset de formulario, para saber cuál se está editando
    formEdit.dataset.index = index;
    // Asignar valor a campo de formulario
    document.querySelector('#edit-task').value = tasksArray[index];
}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const task = document.getElementById('task')
    const tasksText = task.value
    task.value = ''
    if (tasksText === '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea!')
    } else {
        // Insertar elemento en arreglo y mostrar
        redraw(tasksText, -1);
    }
});

formEdit.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const edit = document.getElementById('edit-task');
    const value = edit.value;
    if (value == '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea');
    } else {
        // Cerrar modal
        modal.style.display = 'none';
        // Actualizar valor, en dataset está el índice del elemento
        redraw(value, parseInt(formEdit.dataset.index));
    }
});
//FormSearch
formSearch.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Obtener todas las tareas
    const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
    const value = find.value
    if (value == '') {
        // Mostrar todo
        items.forEach(item => item.style.display = '');
    } else {
        // Ocultar todos
        items.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
        // Mostrar solo coincidencias
        buscar(value).forEach(index => items[index].style.display = '');
    }
})

// Delegar clics para activar botones
tasks.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const item = e.target;
    // Buscar botón por clase
    if (item.classList.contains('delete')) {
        taskDelete(e);
    } else if (item.classList.contains('edit')) {
        taskEdit(e);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.content-left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.content-right {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li>button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    display: inline;
}


/* Modal */

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-left">
            <form id="form-tasks">
                <label>Add a Task</label>
                <input id="task" type="text" placeholder="Task..." />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <form id="form-search">
                <label>Search Task</label>
                <input id="find" type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
                <input id="btn-find" class="find" type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol id="tasks">
        <div id="vacio">
            <h1>No hay tareas...</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- <li>comer <button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>jugar</li> -->
    </ol>

    <!-- Modal -->

    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form-edit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-task" />
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btn-modal" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias por la explicación, me has ayudado bastante, muchas gracias!